# git rebase: copy instead of moving

Tags: git, rebase

My branches are:

```
o---o  support.2013.16
     \
      o---o---o---o---o  master
                       \
                        o---o---o  hotfix/A
```

I need to copy hotfix/A to support.2013.16. I'm aware of cherry-picking, but is it possible to do something like

```
git rebase --onto support.2013.16 master hotfix/A
```

but without moving a branch but copying it instead?

Comment: You could use `git checkout -b <whatever>` first to create the new branch name, then use rebase.  The original `hotfix/A` branch would remain unchanged.

Comment: you mean a new branch based on hotfix/A ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Git `rebase` really does copy the original branch to a new one; but because it moves the branch head, it feels like a move rather than a copy.  If you used `git branch` to add an additional branch head to the original branch, you would still have easy access to the original branch after `git rebase` had made the rebased copy.  So in your example

```
git branch rebased-A hotfix/A
git rebase --onto support.2013.16 master rebased-A
```

leaves you with

```
      o---o---o  rebased-A (hotfix/A')
     /
o---o  support.2013.16
     \
      o---o---o---o---o  master
                       \
                        o---o---o  hotfix/A
```

Comment: Note that this does the same as the other (`git checkout -b`) solution.  (I like this answer better because of the drawn in commit tree. :-) )

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of rebase internals.

Answer (score 10):

You could create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b hotfix/A-support hotfix/A
```

and rebase it instead. So you will have two branches. Maybe you may decide to drop the branch after merging it into the `support` branch.

Alternatively, you could rebase the `hoftix/A` onto the `git merge-base support.2013.16 master` and then you could easily merge the `hotfix/A` into both branches. It will give you prettier history, no duplicate commits.